# Php Email Form Requesting Information

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email

I want to send an email to someone that clicks the link having the information on them from my database. So they put in their username , password, and email and get the 'Item' and 'Aisle' sent to them. The problem is they can have multiple items under their username. So I need to echo all the information in one email. But its not possible to echo information in an email. Currently it sends an email for each item and aisle information found so it can send 2+ emails of information. Any help would be loved. Thanks!

```
$Username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']);
$Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Password']);
$Loc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Loc']);
$To = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['To']);
$Subject = "List";


$query = mysql_query("select * from Members where Username = '$Username' and Password =       '$Password'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$headers = 'From: email@email.com';
$Items = $row['Items'];
$Loc = $row['Loc'];
$msg= "Item: $Items 
Aisle: $Loc\n";
mail($To, $Subject, $msg, 'From:' . $header);
echo 'Email sent to: ' . $To. '<br>';
```

Comment: what is your expected result? Listing all items in 1 email ?

Comment: why can't you echo in an email? retrieve all the rows for a user, build the email, **THEN** send it. you're sending the email for every row of data now.

Comment: Yeah. I would like to send all the results of 'Items' and 'Loc' in one email. Adding in an echo gives me the unexpected T_ECHO error. Feel free to put how you would add an echo and I will test it.

Comment: First check that your query is fetching the proper data or not. do print_r($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)); before the while loop.

Comment: It's fetching properly everything is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the 2nd part of your codes as below:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from Members where Username = '$Username' and Password =       '$Password'");
$items = '';
$headers = 'From: email@email.com';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $items .= $row['Items'] . PHP_EOL;
  $loc = $row['Loc']; // what is Loc ?
}
$msg= "Item: $items 
Aisle: $loc\n";
mail($To, $Subject, $msg, 'From:' . $header);
echo 'Email sent to: ' . $To. '<br>';
```

However, your table structure is weird. You should put your items in a separate table with your member ID as foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the message in a separate file and include it in the message.

like this.

```
$message = include('email_massage.php');
```

Comment: this does not answer OP's question. ( and what will be the contents of `email_message.php` ? )